# Filters / Scipy return

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, filtering

I'm applying some filters using Scipy, as it follows:

```
def sobel_operator(data):
    scipy.misc.imsave('sobel.png', mag)

    mask_x = numpy.array([[-1, 0, +1],
                          [-2, 0, +2],
                          [-1, 0, +2]])
    mask_y = numpy.array([[+1, +2, +1],
                          [0, 0, 0],
                          [-1, -2, -1]])
    dx = ndimage.convolve(data.data, mask_x)
    dy = ndimage.convolve(data.data, mask_y)
    m = numpy.hypot(dx, dy)
    print m
    scipy.misc.imsave('sobel1.png', m)
    m *= 255.0 / numpy.max(m)  # normalize (Q&D)
    print m
    scipy.misc.imsave('sobel2.png', m)
```

Here is my outputs, respectively:

[image]

[image]

The first image is equal second one (uploading here made the images be darker). My doubt is why the second and the first images are the same, since in the first one I'm not applying a normalization, and I have a lot of values > 255 (Here it seems that the value has been truncated to 255, but I know that this is not the case 'cause I'm my computer the image is much more to grayscale then black as here). Does Scipy take cares of it in same way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `mask_x[2,2]` should be `+1`.